# TikZ - Improving alignment across rows

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

Assume four nodes, arranged in two rows, with text inside each of them. Further assume that I would like to arrange these nodes in the following pattern:

```
|----Node A----|  |Node B|
|Node C||Node D|
```

I aligned node C via `anchor=north east` (kind of counter-intuitive, but well ...), yet the combination of nodes C and D is slightly longer than node A on each side.

How can I correct for this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, fit, positioning, shapes.symbols, chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove page number

\begin{document}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block_large} = [rectangle, draw, text width=8cm, rounded corners, text height=0.4cm, text depth=1.25cm]
\tikzstyle{block_medium} = [rectangle, draw, text width=4cm, rounded corners, text height=0.4cm, text depth=1.25cm]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto, comment/.style={rectangle, inner sep=5pt}]
        % Draw nodes - first row
        \node [block_large] (col1_row1) {
            \textbf{Node A}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };

        \node [block_medium, right=1cm of col1_row1] (col3_row1) {
            \textbf{Node B}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };

        % Draw nodes - second row
        \node [block_medium, below=0.1cm of col1_row1, anchor=north east] (col1_row2) {
            \textbf{Node C}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
        \node [block_medium, right=0cm of col1_row2] (col2_row2) {
            \textbf{Node D}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually since you're defining the `text width` of your box, you need to take care, that the `inner sep` adds to the size of the box. Therefore by defining the `inner xsep` and tweaking the size of your boxes results in:

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, fit, positioning, shapes.symbols, chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove page number

\begin{document}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block_large} = [rectangle, draw, text width=8cm, inner xsep=0.25cm, rounded corners, text height=0.4cm, text depth=1.25cm]
\tikzstyle{block_medium} = [rectangle, draw, text width=3.75cm, inner xsep=0.25cm, rounded corners, text height=0.4cm, text depth=1.25cm]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, auto, comment/.style={rectangle, inner sep=5pt}]
        % Draw nodes - first row
        \node [block_large] (col1_row1) {
            \textbf{Node A}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };

        \node [block_medium, right=1cm of col1_row1] (col3_row1) {
            \textbf{Node B}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };

        % Draw nodes - second row
        \node [block_medium, below=0.1cm of col1_row1, anchor=north east] (col1_row2) {
            \textbf{Node C}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
        \node [block_medium, right=0cm of col1_row2] (col2_row2) {
            \textbf{Node D}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of `tikzpicture` may be you could consider `tcolorbox` and its `raster` library which allows to more or less easily organize text boxes.

In this particular case, a result similar to what you want could be done with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{\textbf{Node #1}\\\textit{Foo:} Bar\\\textit{Baz:} Qux}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height=rows, raster columns=3, notitle, colback=white]
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] \mytext{A}
\tcbitem \mytext{B}
\tcbitem \mytext{C}
\tcbitem \mytext{D}
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `inner sep=0pt` (using new style):

```
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {
        rectangle, draw, rounded corners, text depth=1.25cm, 
       text height=0.4cm, inner sep=0pt,
   },
    block_large/.style = {block, 
       text width=8cm,
   },
    block_medium/.style = {block, 
       text width=4cm
   },
}
```

to the node specifications --- `inner sep` is added to other sizes, so you get one in the big box, and two in the smaller ones.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, use `\tikzset` instead.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you! For a few minutes, you had a version posted where the option `inner sep` was set such that the boxes were nicely aligned. That would be my preferred answer.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl I deleted it because it didn't work, `inner sep` was destroying vertical alignement...