# TikZ - Improving alignment across rows - Cont'd

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

The following question is a follow-up to [that post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308149/tikz-improving-alignment-across-rows).

Assume five nodes, arranged in three rows. I would like to arrange these nodes in the following pattern:

```
|----Node A----|  |Node B|
|Node C||Node D|
|----Node E----|
```

Controlling the position of node E is not very intuitive to me.

Using `anchor=north west` results in an incorrect horizontal position:

```
\node [block_large, below=0.1cm of col1_row2, anchor=north west] (col1_row3) {
    \textbf{Node E}\\
    \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
    \textit{Baz:} Qux
};
```

Adding a right shift (`right=-2.11`) results in an incorrect vertical position:

```
\node [block_large, below=0.1cm of col1_row2, anchor=north west, right=-2.11] (col1_row3) {
    \textbf{Node E}\\
    \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
    \textit{Baz:} Qux
};
```

How do you re-establish the alignment for node E?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still follow the relative positioning. I cleaned up the irrelevant parts a bit.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{block large/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=8cm, inner xsep=0.25cm, 
        rounded corners, text height=0.4cm, text depth=1.25cm, 
        node contents=\mycontent{#1},name=#1
    },
    block medium/.style = {block large=#1,text width=3.75cm}
}
\def\mycontent#1{
            \textbf{Node #1}\\
            \textit{Foo:} Bar\\
            \textit{Baz:} Qux
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[block large =A];
\node[block medium=B,anchor=north west,at={([yshift=-1mm]A.south west)}]; 
\node[block medium=C,anchor=north east,at={([yshift=-1mm]A.south east)}]; 
\node[block large =E,anchor=north west,at={([yshift=-1mm]B.south west)} ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And with a similar code from my [answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329671/1952) you can also get this alignment with `tcolorboxes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{\textbf{Node #1}\\\textit{Foo:} Bar\\\textit{Baz:} Qux}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height=rows, raster columns=3, notitle, colback=white]
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] \mytext{A}
\tcbitem \mytext{B}
\tcbitem \mytext{C}
\tcbitem \mytext{D}
\tcbitem[blankest] %We need an empty box to count three in a row
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] \mytext{E}
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]